# java.lang.nullpointerexception when creating array of cookie objects in servlet

Tags: java, arrays, servlets, cookies

have a html form where 4 option buttons are there. when user click submit button servlet wil execute and need to create cookie of selected options.
i wrote following code, but when i "INITIALIZE ARRAY OF OBJECTS OF COOKIES" the nullpointerexception comes.WITHOUT COOKIE INITIALIZATION my program works well.

```
Cookie[] cookie=null; int i=1;
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()){
String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
String[] paramValues = req.getParameterValues(paramName);
String paramValue = paramValues[0];
cookie[i] = new Cookie(paramName, paramValue); **//ERROR IS HERE**
cookie[i].setMaxAge(60*60*24);
resp.addCookie(cookie[i]);
i++}
```

I CHECKeD THE VALUES "paramName, paramValue". i got Correct Answer without Cookie. what will be the error when i initialize array of objects of cookie like this?

Answer (score 1):

cookie is null and you are trying to  access an index of an array which is null.
You should initialize it this way:

```
Cookie[] cookie = new Cookie[someNumber];
```

Comment: it works. but i have one problem, when i tried to get this cookies via "GetCookie" servlet. i Got it in firefox(default browser), but doesn't get cookie in Chrome! why? (am using fedora 20)

Comment: I don't have enough information about it, so I wouldn't know without see the code.
I'd suggest you to post another question about it with your source code and detailing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the array of Cookies.

use `Cookie[] cookie=new Cookie[SIZE]` instead of `Cookie[] cookie=null` to initialize it before assigning a value to it.